# populate treeview tree from simple sql table

Tags: c#, sql

In general, so, I have four tables with a relationship in the order of subordination, Macroobject-Superobject-Object, I have attached a connection diagram, I have been trying to turn it into a tree for a long time, but this is not the question (although I will not refuse help). I just started learning C #, I have zero experience. in general, the problem is that the treeview output window does not fill, just an empty white square, tell me - what am I missing? Well, how to implement filling from the rest of the tables?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Loadtree()
        {
            DataTable treeTable1 = this.выборСуперОбъектTableAdapter.GetData();
            foreach (DataRow dr in treeTable1.Select("МакроКод is null"))
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
                node.Text = (string)dr["макрообъект"];
                node.Tag = dr["МакроКод"];
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
                AddNodes(node);
            }
 
        }
        private void AddNodes(TreeNode node)
        {
            DataTable treeTable1 = this.выборМакроОбъектTableAdapter1.GetData();
            foreach (DataRow dr in treeTable1.Select("суперобъект = " + node.Tag.ToString()))
            {
                TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode();
                node1.Text = (string)dr["суперобъект"];
                node1.Tag = dr["макрообъект"];
                node.Nodes.Add(node1);
            }
        }
 
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "bdsiDataSet.ВыборСуперОбъект". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
            //this.выборСуперОбъектTableAdapter.Fill(this.bdsiDataSet.ВыборСуперОбъект);
 
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This code looks ok. I guess the problem is where you actually call this `AddNodes` method. Either you don't call it at all or you call it incorrectly (e.g. you pass `node` that itself is not in the tree).

Comment: Well, I guess I'll wait till the question is actually asked. This is the third version of the code in the question and comments don't make sense if the code still changes.

Comment: how and what needs to be changed or added?

Comment: It looks like if `МакроКод is null`  then your Tag property doesn't have any value.

Comment: need to be changed to 0? if so, tried it, to no avail

Comment: Where you calling Loadtree() ?

Comment: Assuming this is the final version of the code, it doesn't seem like `Loadtree` is called.

Comment: should fill in by itself when opening the form

Comment: `should fill in by itself when opening the form`  Not if nothing is calling `Loadtree`  Put `Loadtree()` in the `Form2_Load` block.

Comment: how to write it in the code and in what place?

Comment: by the way, and private void Loadtree ()
is that not what you mean?

Comment: Put `Loadtree();` under the `InitializeComponent();` line.

Answer (score 0):

So?

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
public Form2()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         DataTable treeTable = this.выборМакроОбъектTableAdapter1.GetData();
         foreach (DataRow dr in treeTable.Select("МакроКод is null"))
         {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
                node.Text = (string)dr["макрообъект"];
                node.Tag = dr["МакроКод"];
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
                AddNodes(node);
         }

        }
        private void AddNodes(TreeNode node)
        {
            DataTable treeTable1 = this.выборСуперОбъектTableAdapter.GetData();
            foreach (DataRow dr in treeTable1.Select("суперобъект = " + node.Tag.ToString()))
            {
                TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode();
                node1.Text = (string)dr["суперобъект"];
                node1.Tag = dr["макрообъект"];
                node.Nodes.Add(node1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This could possibly work. However, avoid creating answers to your own questions that are not answers but new questions.

Comment: Also avoid non-english comments when other people mostly don't speak your language. As for your issue, put a breakpoint in the `TreeNode node = new TreeNode();` line. Is the line called at all?

Comment: I set a breakpoint, but how to find out whether the line is being triggered or not?

Comment: Run the code from within the VS using "Start debugging".

Comment: ok, screenshot what i did is that what you need?

Comment: [link] (https://ibb.co/vkYCWFs) this is the link to the screenshot

Comment: It is, however, you should be looking at your code in a debugging session.  From there you could inspect your objects and check if the table adapter is filled correctly and if the tree is actually initialized. I really recommend you follow any tutorial on debugging.

Comment: during step-by-step debugging, F11 does not go beyond the opening of the form, debugging stops and pressing F11 does not respond.

Comment: so nothing worked, does anyone have any ideas?